# Avoid table moved to end of text

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

I have some table, spanning about 17 lines and despite specifying `\begin{table}[t!]` it gets placed at the end of the text at the center of its own page. How can this be prevented and the table forced to be placed on the top of the same page as the text?

So far, I had the impression that larger tables get moved to the end of the text. So I guess my question is more generally how to keep them in the text, too.

Comment: upload code and output

Comment: I find it hard to come up with a MWE for placement.

Comment: Hard to guess without code. Probably the lipsum package `\usepackage{lipsum}` helps to create a MWE?

Comment: I will try. However, my question is more generally how to prevent tables from being moved to the end of the text. I have amended the post.

Comment: This happens if the table does not fit on the page. If your table is that large, maybe `longtable`  is an option?

Comment: All tables do fit on a page but some with only one or two lines of text below. I would also be fine with the table taking a full page but it should then sit between text pages and not at the end of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the regular classes (e.g., `book`, `report`, `article`, `memoir`, etc.) the defaults are: max of 2 floats at the top of the page and taking up no more than 70% of the text height. Either these have been changed in your document or your table is too tall. As you have not provided an MWE how are we to tell? --- GOM

For more information read section *10.4 Where LaTeX puts floats* in the `memoir` manual (`texdoc memoir`).